# How to: WCF Service check if Windows Forms user is still active?

Tags: c#, winforms, session, windows-mobile

I have the following scenario: A Windows Mobile 6.1 (.NET Compact Framwork 2.0) Forms application (running in several devices simultanisly) that consumes several WCF services from a server. To use the windows Form app, users must login.

The server consumes data from a SAP system. The WCF server must retrive some information from SAP based on the logged users. So, my Windows forms app must (from time to time) show that they`re still runing to my WCF server.

What can I do to accomplish this task? I was thinking in create a background task that update the SQL server of the WCF server. (like a session control).

Comment: Why not add one WCF service that is just a SillAlive(UserName) function and call that from a background thread or a timer in your device's forms application?

Comment: WCF needs to know which devices are alive in a certain time. Since some devices can eventually freeze or run out battery or get disconected (out of wi-fi range) i can`t simply relly in the serviec getting called. That`s why I though in control the state using SQL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could listen for [Power State](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa929251.aspx) changes in your application. The documentation shows it is only available for Windows Mobile 6.5, but I use it in my Windows Mobile 5.0 applications running .NET CF 3.5.

Like a cell phone, if the mobile device is not used for a long time, the OS will show that the battery is at the same level until it actually gets used. So, it isn't very reliable.

However, you could listen for events ([like POWER_STATE_CRITICAL](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa931596.aspx), etc) and have your software make changes that interact with your WCF server accordingly.

Below is an edited version of something like what I use.

This will not solve your problem 100%, but it should give you an idea of how to do what you need.

```
using Microsoft.WindowsMobile.Status;

BatteryLevel _batteryLevel;
BatteryState _batteryState;

void Mobile5_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  _batteryLevel = (BatteryLevel)SystemState.GetValue(SystemProperty.PowerBatteryStrength);
  _batteryState = (BatteryState)SystemState.GetValue(SystemProperty.PowerBatteryState);
  if (!BatteryCritical(false)) {
    // Continue
  }
}
/// <summary>
/// Sets the Battery Level and Battery State for the Mobile Device
/// <para><value>showDialog=True show the dialog box</value></para>
/// <para><value>Returns True <b>if</b> the battery is in a critical state</value></para>
/// </summary>
/// <param name="showDialog">Do you want a dialog box to be displayed or not?</param>
/// <returns>false if the Battery is NOT in the critical state</returns>
bool BatteryCritical(bool showDialog) {
  _batteryAlert = false;
  bool bad = false; // everything starts out ok. We are actually running, after all.
  _batteryLevel = (BatteryLevel)SystemState.GetValue(SystemProperty.PowerBatteryStrength);
  _batteryState = (BatteryState)SystemState.GetValue(SystemProperty.PowerBatteryState);
  bool present = ((_batteryState & BatteryState.NotPresent) != BatteryState.NotPresent);
  bool charging = ((_batteryState & BatteryState.Charging) == BatteryState.Charging);
  bool critical = ((_batteryState & BatteryState.Critical) == BatteryState.Critical);
  bool lowbatry = ((_batteryState & BatteryState.Low) == BatteryState.Low);
  Color c;
  if (present) {
    if (charging) {
      c = Color.Cyan;
    } else {
      if (critical) {
        c = Color.Orange;
        _batteryAlert = true;
      } else if (lowbatry) {
        c = Color.Yellow;
        _batteryAlert = true;
      } else {
        c = Color.White;
      }
    }
  } else {
    c = Color.Silver;
  }
  StatusPanel.BackColor = c;
  switch (_batteryLevel) {
    case BatteryLevel.VeryHigh: // (81-100%)
      BatteryPanel.BackColor = Color.Cyan;
      break;
    case BatteryLevel.High: // (61-80%)
      BatteryPanel.BackColor = Color.Lime;
      break;
    case BatteryLevel.Medium: // 41-60%)
      BatteryPanel.BackColor = Color.Yellow;
      break;
    case BatteryLevel.Low: // (21-40%)
      BatteryPanel.BackColor = Color.Orange;
      //WirelessUpdate(RadioState.Off, false);
      break;
    case BatteryLevel.VeryLow: // (0-20%)
      BatteryPanel.BackColor = Color.Red;
      //WirelessUpdate(RadioState.Off, false);
      bad = (!charging && present);
      break;
  }
  if (showDialog) {
    string msg = string.Format("Level is {0}\r\nState is {1}", _batteryLevel, _batteryState);
    if (_batteryLevel == BatteryLevel.Low) {
      msg += "\r\n\r\nThe wireless radio will be inactive until it has been charged.";
    } else if (bad == true) {
      msg += "\r\n\r\nThis Application will now close to preserve the device. Please return it to a charging base immediately.";
    }
    MessageBox.Show(msg, "Battery Meter", MessageBoxButtons.OKCancel, MessageBoxIcon.None, 0);
  }
  if (!bad) {
    StatusPanel.Refresh();
    // You could signal your app here
  } else {
    // Tell your app this device needs to turn off now.
  }
  return bad;
}
```

Comment: Well, it does not solve my problem directly, although it helped and helped to solve another one of my problems as well. The only problem is that I`m using CF 2.0 and I can`t change to 3.5...

Comment: You can install CF 3.5. It is probably already on your development PC. See [How to: Install the .NET Compact Framework on a Device](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb788171(v=vs.90).aspx). Personally, I use the install with Windows Explorer option instead of deploying it with the device, because the deploy with device option makes all of your builds take too long.

Comment: You will have to install CF 3.5 before installing your app, then the `WinMobil` device will tell you it needs to reboot. After the reboot, install your application. Easy Peasy! :)

Comment: Tks mate! I sure know that I can install! But the thing is: I can`t install it because of enterprise limitations! But tks a lot for your help and consideration!